# First use of American football fields as measurement

Tags: etymology, north-american-english

In some books and documentaries, American football fields are used as units of measurement for length (100 yards) and sometimes area. For example, a book might say

> The iceberg was the size of six football fields.

to show how gargantuan it is.

**When is the first recorded usage of American football fields in this way?**

Comment: Not just American; British usage has 'the size of six football pitches'.

Answer (score 3):

The earliest example I've been able to find (so far) in which "football fields" are used as units of linear measure is from "[Jack Coffey in Flying Picture](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=TDB19440512-01.1.4&txq=%22as+long+as%22+%22football+fields%22)" in the *[Greencastle, Indiana] Daily Banner* (May 12, 1944):

> Flying plane No. 4 in the picture is Jack Coffey of Greencastle, and he is shown in a close-up in a morning worship aboard the huge carrier which is **as long as three football fields**.

It isn't clear whether the writer is measuring from goal line to goal line or from back of the end zone to back of the end zone, but I suspect that the former is the intended sense—here and in subsequent instances of linear measurement by football field.

**------------**

Three somewhat earlier instances use "football fields" as units of measure for area. From "[Lost and Found!](https://news.hrvh.org/veridian/cgi-bin/senylrc?a=d&d=rocklandctytimes19340217.1.5&txq=%22ten+football+fields%22)" in the *[Haverstraw, New York] Rockland County Times* (February 17, 1934):

> Down here you'll see a tiny crack you could hardly put a knife blade into. A few minutes later it is three feet wide and you're sprinting away from it as fast as you can go. In half an hour a piece of territory **as big as ten football fields**, with a horrible grinding sound, has slid into the ocean, which is 1600 feet deep around these parts and darn cold. Nice stuff to sleep on. eh?

From "[Kaiser Promises New Shipbuilding Record](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SBS19420811.1.2&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522four+football+fields%252522-------1)," in the *San Bernardino [California] Sun* (August 11, 1942):

> The new plant, **as large as four football fields**, operates something like sub-assembly plants in the automobile and aviation industry, and feeds completed sections of ships to assemblymen on the ways.

And from "[Aerial View of Orange Senior High School and Deeded Property](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth221220/m1/1/zoom/?q=%22three%20football%20fields%22&resolution=4&lat=2391.54803521145&lon=1966.9672492960308)," in the *Orange [Texas] Leader* (December 24, 1942):

> Upper right is West End Park comprising a sodded area **equivalent to three football fields** complete with grandstand, bleachers, clubhouse, floodlights, etc.

Earlier still are instances in which areas are defined by how many football fields it could contain. For example, from an [advertisement for Atwater Kent Radio](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=DKD19251112.1.5&txq=%2522ten+football+fields%2522) in the *DeKalb [Illinois] Daily Chronicle* (November 12, 1925):

> **Larger than ten football fields**
>
> Here is the factory that stands behind our recommendation of Atwater Kent Sets and Radio Speakers. It **covers more ground than ten football fields** or sixty-four baseball diamonds.

From "[Gulfport Pier](https://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=HR19391222.2.13&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22six+football+fields%22-------)," in the *[Monterey, Virginia] Highland Recorder* (December 22, 1939):

> A pier at Gulfport, Miss., is large enough to **contain six football fields**.

**------------**

Other countries seem have used area measurements based on the size of their football fields, as well. For example, from "[Largest British Liner: The Ship Beautiful: Luxury on the Aquitania](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/128073316?searchTerm=%22eight+football+fields%22)," in the *Maitland [New South Wales] Weekly Mercury* (May 29, 1914), reprinted from the *London Daily Telegraph*:

> The Aquitania is just over 300 yards long, so that a walk round the ship from bow to stern and back would represent a distance of about one-third of a mile.
>
> Her deck space is computed to be **equal to that of eight football fields** rolled into one.

Answer (score 2):

It was certainly used in 1960:

> The SS Cosmic is approximately 745 feet long and has approximately 700
>   feet of ship in front of the bridge, or wheelhouse. This is
>   approximately 2½ football fields in front of the person doing the
>   navigating.

[[Public Works Appropriations, 1960: Civil functions, Department of the Army US Congress](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=t2s9AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA2865&lpg=PA2865&dq=%22the+size+of%22+%22football+fields%22+1960&source=bl&ots=LcIxvMQIoq&sig=ACfU3U0hDSoIFg-vvDW2mpTUXjl7-nokMw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTvNnT1MblAhXUUBUIHRYuB10Q6AEwF3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20size%20of%22%20%22football%20fields%22%201960&f=false).

One surely has also to consider the following:

> **stadium** ...
>
> 2  An ancient Roman or Greek measure of length, about 185 metres
>   (originally the length of a stadium).

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/stadium)]

Comment: OT: a comparison that made me smile was in a book about the *Queen Mary* which stated that a walk of "three times round the deck is 1.6 km." This odd statistic was clearly an update of "three times round the deck is a mile." It would have been more meaningful as "twice round the deck is a kilometre."

Comment: The _Queen Mary_? I'm surprised they didn't use leagues. But thanks for the nudge; I'll adjust the answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - The leagues were busy at the football fields.